# Dynamically created component is not binding to the model on model change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

My goal is on emitting of new value to the item$ property of the dynamically created component, restore component state to default state which is stored in object. But clearly component is not picking up the model changes.

I have tried to run the change detection on the component on each time new value is emitted. But still not picking up the value.

I have reproduced the problem here in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyhfku.

In above code HelloComponent is reusable component and HeroComponent is dynamic component which hosts HelloComponent (sorry for naming). On AppComponent I have a onclick method which emits new value on each click. Also you can change the state of each item on the DOM. But I'd like on each new value restore the state of the HeroComponent which I am trying to accomplish on Subscription but not working

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Dynamically created components - try to change this to standard way and you still will have the same problem. It's about how you pass simple values to section/hello component, how you change them and how change detection mechanism in Angular works. After you change values in SectionComponent, from HeroComponent perespective nothing has really changed, Input values for SectionComponents are the same. Try to add another simple number Input property to SectionComponent, change this in HeroComponent and you will se that onChanges works fine:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-za4mkd

I dont now what you want to achive, so I cant tell you right way to code this, but maybe you should consider using Control Value Accessor (if this has to be some sort of checkbox in form?). 
Also you should remember that for objects (like data structures) Angular see changes only if reference changed (you can use spread operator to create a new instance of data structures).